# Web app data storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, storage

Let's say I have two or more tabs with a couple of inputs and textareas. 
Users can fill these fields and switch tabs but I want to make sure they don't lose the data in the fields.

Here comes the question: how would you save the data when the users switch between tabs? 
Now I solved this problem by storing the data in variables, specifically in object literal (Javascript), but it is such a mechanical way to do it.

Of course I could push the data in a database.

I am using Javascript plus jQuery. I would really like to think of a good way to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: When do you want to save the data so that on a return visit to the page, the user sees the saved data?

Comment: No , this is not the issue. The goal is to let the user see the data he saved in the session he's using.

Comment: Just store it in the client-side Javascript. The database is for persisting information between sessions (or from a session to something else), not within a session. IMHO/AFAIK.

Comment: I guess this question should be on Stack Overflow.

Comment: how can i migrate it without copy and paste manually to StackOverflow?

Comment: The moderators will move the question over to SO if it's a better fit there - you don't have to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `localStorage`.

Just set the values you want to store by:

```
localStorage.setItem(key, stringData);
```

To get the data:

```
var stringData = localStorage.getItem(key);
```

To delete:

```
localStorage.removeItem(key);
```

That way the data is stored locally in the user's browser. User can also come back later and data will still be there.

You can synchronize the tabs by listening the `storage` event:

```
window.addEventListener('storage', updateStorage, false);

function updateStorage(e) {

    if (e.newValue === null) {
        localStorage.removeItem(e.key);

    } else {
        localStorage.setItem(e.key, e.newValue);
    }

}
```

The `storage`event is only throw to the *inactive* tabs so they can update the isolated copy of the `localStorage`.

If you only need to store the data for a session you can use `sessionStorage` instead.

For more on `localStorage`:
http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/PR-webstorage-20130409/

Comment: really nice answer but. Isn't local storage only for the latest browsers?

Comment: You need a HTML5 enabled browser. Though, IE8 supports localStorage so the no rule without exception :) Except from Opera Mini (and possible Lynx), all browsers support localStorage today (see http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage)